# How to upgrade nuget with Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

While installing this package **Microsoft.Net.Http** via Nuget console I got this error:

```
Install-Package : The 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.28' package requires NuGet client version '2.8.1' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.6.40627.9000'.
```

- Please How can I upgrade my Nuget to version 2.8.1?

I Cant find anything easily on google.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

To update NuGet in Visual Studio to the latest version you can use the Extensions Manager.

1. From the Tools menu select Extensions and Updates.
2. Then in the dialog that opens select the Updates tab.
3. Then select Visual Studio Gallery.
4. Select NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio and click the Update button.

If you want to install NuGet 2.8.1 you can download the Visual Studio installer (VSIX) from NuGet's [CodePlex web site](http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/118318)

Comment: Does NuGet for VS2012 max out at NuGet 2.8.6? I'm getting a similar error to the poster but it is asking for at least version 2.12. I am following the same steps as above (in addition to also trying uninstalling and reinstalling NuGet Package Manager) but it shows no updates available and installs at 2.8.6.

Comment: Yes, NuGet for VS 2012 only supports up to NuGet 2.8. You can see the latest version from the [gallery page](https://www.visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c). VS 2013 supports up to NuGet 2.12 as shown on its [gallery page](https://www.visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4ec1526c-4a8c-4a84-b702-b21a8f5293ca)

Comment: is there a way I can do it via the cli?  my client has blocked the IE.  thx!

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Update Visual Studio from the command line? Or update the package?

Comment: There is no such thing "Extensions and Updates" any more. 99% of the links when I try to find out how to update NuGet are about *using* Nuget to update other packages :-(

Comment: This is quite an old question and answer. This was back when NuGet was not distributed with Visual Studio on Windows, but was a separate extension to be installed.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Go to the Manage NuGet Packages and click Update button

Answer (score -3):

Go to Menu and select Tools => NuGet Package Manager => Package Manager Console
and type the below command:

```
PM> Install-Package NuGet.Client -Version 4.2.0
```

For more info: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Client/

Comment: This installs NuGet libraries into current project, not globally in Visual Studio, which is what I think the OP needs.