# Visual Studio Professional 2012 error: This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, git, visual-studio-2012

I just installed Visual Studio Professional 2012. I opened an ASP.NET MVC project I made earlier on a different computer. Here's the error list:
[image]

I tried the steps suggested in the error list, but it didn't help.

If I change the target framework to .NET framework 4.5.2, the references stop showing as invalid, but I still get errors:

> The 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.2.0' package requires NuGet client version '2.8.50313' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.6.40619.9041'.  C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\repo.nuget\nuget.targets
>
> The command ""C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\repo.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\repo\NewsAgency\packages.config" -source ""  -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\repo\ "" exited with code 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried [upgrading NuGet Package Manager](https://forums.asp.net/t/1776324.aspx?How+to+install+upgrade+VS+NuGet+Package+Manager+)?

Comment: The errors are pretty clear: For the first, install Nuget. For the second,  you **require Nuget client version 2.8.50313, but you only have Nuget client version 2.6.40619**. Upgrade your Nuget client from version 2.6 to 2.8. It's really helpful if you learn to read the words in the error message. They're not just there to take up space on your screen; they actually contain information. :-)

Comment: I did it, now it changed to this error: Error 33 The "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\newsagency1\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.1.0\build\..\tools\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your nuget.

You can [download here](http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/118318).

There are [others questions about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384885/how-to-upgrade-nuget-with-visual-studio-express-2012) here.

Comment: Well thanks, I tried it, now the 2 errors are gone, but there's a new error: "The "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc" task could not be loaded from the assembly (...)"

Comment: @Supercat check your project references, maybe you'll need to remove and add the reference manually. Or try to reinstall: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/