# Twilio is not working on visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, twilio

i was trying to install twilio package on vs2012 it didn't word, then i update the nuget versions since it wasn't compatible but also it didn't work..
they wrote for me this message ( 'Twilio' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens')
any help please..

Comment: Please update the question with details about: what type of project this is, what version of .net you are targeting, what the name of the (full) name of the twilio nuget package you're trying to install and the full error message that's being returned.

Comment: Install-Package : 'Twilio' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Twilio
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
 this is th full code ...

Comment: iam using c# with .net framework to send sms to some clients

Comment: This might be related to the version of nuget that you are using.  Are you able to update it and then try again?

Comment: how can i update it ?
since i tried updating it from the extensions and update from the sample gallery

Comment: You tried these things? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384885/how-to-upgrade-nuget-with-visual-studio-express-2012